# Is it possible run Selenium test without active desktop and Jenkins slave?

Tags: windows, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-cli

I have a **Windows Server 2012 server**, with **Jenkins** and **Selenium** tests project on this server.

I want to run my tests on the server via **Jenkins rebuild event**. 
Is it possible run **Selenium tests in browsers** (Firefox, Chrome and IE) **directly on this server, without separate slave machine**?

Comment: Yes it is possible. First install all required and supported browsers on your windows server. And start jenkins (you can schedule your tests if you want) and start the build. And change the node details to localhost (if you are using grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible run Selenium tests in browsers (Firefox, Chrome and IE) directly on this server, without separate slave machine?

Of course.

You have two options:

1. You can setup a Grid, with only your computer as the node (connecting to itself)
2. Since it's Windows, it *does* have a desktop and you will be able to run tests just by setting `webdriver.chrome|ie.driver` and as easy as instantiating `Chrome|IEDriver()`